# Count number of substrings in String by multiple delimiters

Tags: python, string, substring, delimiter

Imagine the following example Strings

1. ‘John @ Mary      John v Mary      John vs Mary’
2. ‘John v Mary    Ben v Paul   John v Mary’
3. ‘Hello World / John v Mary    John @ Mary    John vs Mary’
4. ‘John v Mary   John vs Mary        John @ Mary     John v Mary’

There are 3 identified delimiters

- ' @ '
- ' v '
- ' vs '

For every field row in my file, I would like to iterate through each delimiter, look left and right by 4 characters, concatenate left and right together, and return the count should all concatenated substrings match.

1. we would end up finding 'JohnMary' 3 times. Return = 3
2. we would end up finding 'JohnMary','BenPaul' and 'JohnMary'. Return = 0
3. we would end up finding 'JohnMary' 3 times. *note the Hello World is irrelevant as we only look 4 characters left and right*. Return = 3
4. we would end up finding 'JohnMary' 4 times. Return = 4

For this I'll need some sort recursive/loop query to iterate through each delimiter in each row, and count the number of matched substrings.

- note, if the first 2 substrings encountered aren't a match, we don't need to continue checking any further and can return 0 (like in example 2)

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself so far?

Comment: I only have knowledge to try something in SQL (but couldn't get there). I had an earlier question but all the comments kept saying string manipulation is not suited to SQL and it should be done in a programming language, then an admin closed it to new comments. I've now opened a new question and now tagged it Python for this reason

Comment: Here are some references that can help you, https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_slice.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code that assumes always exists a space before and after the delimiter

```
!/usr/bin/python3

import re
from copy import deepcopy
from typing import List, Tuple, Union

def count_match(s: str, d: List[str]) -> Tuple[Union[None, str], int, int]:

    if len(s) == 0:
        return None, 0, 0

    counter = dict()
    offset = 0
    for each in d:
        match = re.search(each, s)
        if match is None:
            break
        idx = match.start()
        sub_string1 = s[idx-4: idx]
        sub_string2 = s[idx+len(each): idx+len(each)+4]
        sub_string = ''.join((sub_string1, sub_string2))
        offset = max(offset, idx+len(each)+4)
        try:
            counter[sub_string] += 1
        except KeyError:
            counter[sub_string] = 1
    if not len(counter):
        return None, 0, 0
    if len(counter.keys()) > 1:
        return None, -1, 0
    return sub_string, list(counter.values())[0], offset


if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = 'John @ Mary John v Mary John vs Mary John @ Mary'
    delimiter = [' @ ', ' v ', ' vs ']
    count = 0
    ref_string = ""
    while text:
        string, partial, start = count_match(text, delimiter)
        if string != ref_string and ref_string != "":
            count = 0
            break
        if partial == -1:
            count = 0
            break
        if partial == 0:
            break
        ref_string = string
        count += partial
        text = text[start:]

    print(count)
```

Comment: Thanks Ulisse it works great! How could this be amended slightly to import a CSV file with 2 columns 'Event' and 'ID', and iterate through all 20 million rows in 'Event'?

Comment: Use this line of code to read the csv file
```
import csv
with open("file.csv", newline='') as fin:
        reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=',')
        for record in reader:
            text = record[0]
```
Here file.csv is the filename of the csv and I assumed that the field separator in the file is the comma and the field you want to process is the first one.
The you can arrange the code in the main into a function a pass text to it

Comment: FYI I basically need to create a new column into my file (dateframe?) with the return value of each row. Have tried since you wrote the comment all sorts of ways to even import the file in the first place but it gives me invalid syntax errors no matter how I fiddle with it. Don't want to waste your time but would appreciate the help if you're still feeling generous! I'm just not knowledgeable enough with Python for only hints. p.s. my file is a txt file, with a tab delimiter

Comment: I see that the issue was that I thought import csv was part of the same line as with open, doh! I have it working and it can read the file :) Now I just need to save all the results into a new column

Answer (score 0):

Got this answer from a Matthew Barnett on a Python help forum. It also works great :)

```
text = '''\
John @ Mary John v Mary John vs Mary
John v Mary Ben v Paul John v Mary
Hello World / John v Mary John @ Mary John vs Mary
John v Mary John vs Mary John @ Mary John v Mary
'''

from collections import defaultdict

import re
pattern = re.compile('(.{4})( @ | v | vs )(.{4})')

for line in text.splitlines():
    found = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

    for before, sep, after in pattern.findall(line):
        key = before, sep, after
        found[before + after] += 1

    if len(found) == 1 and sum(found.values()) > 1:
        print(list(found.values())[0])
    else:
        print(0)
```